# What's the equivalent averageifs for standard deviation?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, standard-deviation

I have asked aboutand already got answer about **averageifs excel function** 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41168399/how-to-use-averageif-function). However, I was also wondering if I can get standard deviation for the same data set in new column. 
 [Here is the screenshot of sample data:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nYF8.jpg)

Answer (score 6):

You can use an array formula to first filter through your rows and then apply the standard deviation to the sample. Formula would look like this:

```
=STDEV.S(IF((IF(C:C="alpha",1,0)*IF(D:D="S14",1,0))=1,B:B,""))
```

Inputted using `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER`. Cheers,

As provided by @ScottCraner in the comments the much improved formula:

```
=STDEV.S(IF((C:C="alpha")*(D:D="S14"),B:B))
```

Comment: `=STDEV.S(IF((C:C="alpha")*(D:D="S14"),B:B))` is all that is needed.

Comment: Also FWIW:  Make sure to limit the data references to only that of the data set to avoid unnecessary calculations.

Comment: @ScottCraner I might be missing a point here but, '=STDEV.S(IF((IF(C:C=C2,1,0)*IF(D:D=D2,1,0))=1,B:B,""))' gives same value in all cells. Isn't it a better way to write, if I don't want to type othr elements in columns C and D ?

Comment: @alpha189 Enter the formula this way.  Select only E2.  Put the formula in the formula bar.  Hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mode, Excel should put `{}` around the formula if done correctly.  When you have the `{}` around the formula. Drag/copy the formula down.  This is an array formula and must be entered properly.